# bootstrap fluid grid: input breaks out of its container in ie7

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

Why in IE7 input breaks out of its container?

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8jPM/2/

[image]

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6 " style="background:green;">
                        <input type="text" class="span12">
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6" style="background:blue;">
                        <input type="text" class="span12">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6" style="background:green;">
                        <input type="text" class="span12">
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6" style="background:blue;">
                        <input type="text" class="span12">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

UPDATE: I suppose it's box-model and width issue, but is any solution with bootstrap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this happens because IE7 does not support the css property

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

that considers padding and border size as part of the elements width.

read more about this property here: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

because of this, IE7 adds the padding and border size to the input width - exceeding the parent width. You will have to set those to 0 in order to get the element fit to the parent size and stay fluid.

you could try adding a wrapper element around the input and then setting the padding and border to the wrapper. This will work in all browsers

Comment: yepp, thank you, I hoped that it has some kind of magic for this out of the box :)

Comment: eh good old IE7! I've added a line to my answer that should help you to achieve the same result :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I resolved it by replacing

```
class="span3"
```

with

```
class="input-mini"
```

You could use input-small or whatever suits of course. Since you were looking for span12 for your inputs I'd suggest "input-xxlarge"